# Python and ShutdownBlockReasonCreate, ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy, and ShutdownBlockReasonQuery

Tags: python, winapi

Is it possible to call the `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`, `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy`, and `ShutdownBlockReasonQuery` win32 APIs from within Python? I can't find them anywhere in the `pywin32` library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ctypes

```
from ctypes import *
retval = windll.user32.ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(
    handle,
    c_wchar_p("the reason")
)
if retval != 0:
    ... Error checking
```

And similarly with ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I didn't know what DLL it was in.

Comment: search for it in msdn, all api function doc lists the dll at the bottom of the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try asking or making an enhancement request on the pywin32 mailing list:

- http://sourceforge.net/mail/?group_id=78018

If you can't wait and no COM object to be found, there is always [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).  Just about anything can be done with it.